# I Want to sort user that have a date older than today powershell

Tags: azure, powershell

I want to sort user that have an expired date older than today.

For that we have a csv file we create with :

For example today is (european date) : 12.02.2021

I want to sort that csv file (below) in a new csv file with just the UPN (without the date) that are older than today

| upn | date |
| --- | --- |
| test.user1@abc.onmicrosoft.com | 12.02.2021 |
| test.user1@abc.onmicrosoft.com | 10.02.2021 |
| test.user1@abc.onmicrosoft.com | 22.02.2021 |
| test.user1@abc.onmicrosoft.com | 10.09.2019 |

```
$csv = Import-Csv C:\Tools\AccountsDate.csv
$csv
$dateToday = get-date -Format "dd.MM.yyyy"
Write-host "Today we are the :" $dateToday
$Content =$csv.upn | Where-Object -Property date -LT $date
$Content
$Content | Out-File 'C:\Tools\LicencesToRemove.csv'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# this for get example data
$csv = (@"
upn date
--- ---- 
test.user1@abc.onmicrosoft.com 12.02.2021 
test.user1@abc.onmicrosoft.com 10.02.2021 
test.user1@abc.onmicrosoft.com 22.02.2021 
test.user1@abc.onmicrosoft.com 10.09.2019
"@  -replace "--- ----\s+", "") | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter " "

# in your case 
# $csv = Import-Csv "yourFileName.csv" -Delimiter " "

$csv.Where{[datetime]::Parse($_.Date) -lt [datetime]::Today} | Tee-Object -Variable out | Export-Csv "d:\tmp\out.csv" -Delimiter " "
$out
```

After you import the file, you will receive an array that contains [PSCustomObjects] with file fields and values, you iterate over the array elements and exclude those objects whose field value is less than the current one

```
$csv.GetType()
$csv[0].GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
True     False    PSCustomObject                           System.Object
```

Comment: I think OPs input is an actual CSV file, not formatted as table. I think they just copy-pasted formatted output of `$csv`.

Comment: thank you, somehow I didn't think about it

Answer (score 0):

You could do like below:

```
$csv = Import-Csv -Path 'C:\Tools\AccountsDate.csv'
$today = (Get-Date).Date  # Today as of midnight
$filtered = $csv | Where-Object { [datetime]::ParseExact($_.date, 'dd.MM.yyyy', $null) -lt $today } | 
                   Sort-Object upn | Select-Object upn

# output on screen
$filtered

# output to new CSV file
$filtered | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\Tools\OlderUPN.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Result:

```
upn                           
---                           
test.user1@abc.onmicrosoft.com
test.user1@abc.onmicrosoft.com
```